# Does DDH hold in $Z_N^*$ where N is product of 2 large primes

Tags: diffie-hellman, hardness-assumptions

I know that DDH does not hold in $Z_p^*$ because given $g, g^a, g^b, x$, we can compute legendre symbols of $g^a, g^b$ and compare it with legendre symbol of $x$. The same attack doesn't work when we consider the group $Z_N^*$ where N is product of 2 large primes. This is because computing jacobi symbol without knowing factors of N is hard by Quadratic Residuocity assumption. So, does DDH assumption hold in $Z_N^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The same attack doesn't work when we consider the group $Z_N^*$ where N is product of 2 large primes. This is because computing jacobi symbol without knowing factors of N is hard by Quadratic Residuocity assumption.

This is incorrect: computing the Jacobi symbol can always be done in polynomial time, and does not require knowing the factorization. You're confusing it with the hardness of computing *residuosity* (i.e., checking whether an element of $Z_N^*$ is a square). DDH does not hold over $Z_N^*$. It is however conjectured to hold over $J_N$, the subgroup of elements with Jacobi symbol 1, see pages 23-24 of [my paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/990.pdf).

EDIT: a screenshot of some old slides of mine: each element of $Z_N^*$ can have Jacobi symbol 1 or -1, and if it has Jacobi symbol 1, be square or non-square.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol This article describes how to compute Jacobi symbol of a given factors of n. May I know how to compute Jacobi symbol without the factors?

Comment: Legendre symbol in $Z_p$ denotes whether an element is a square mod p. Doesn't Jacobi symbol in $Z_N$ denote whether an element is a square mod N? Why is comptuing jacobi symbol different from computing residuocity?

Comment: @satya: to compute the Jacobi symbol, you can use the exact same algorithm used to compute the Legendre symbol.  And, no, a Jacobi symbol doesn't indicate whether an element is a quadratic residue; a QR will necessarily have a QR of 1 (or 0); however, there are nonQR elements with Jacobi symbol 1

Comment: @satya: an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ (where $n=pq$) will be a QR if $x$ is a QR mod $p$ **AND** $x$ is a QR mod $q$.  $x$ will have Jacobi symbol 1 if $x$ is a QR mod $p$ **XOR** $x$ is a QR mod $q$

Comment: @poncho To compute legendre symbol of a (mod p), I compute $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. To compute jacobi symbol of a (mod N = pq), I compute $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}.a^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$. So, I should at least know $(p-1).(q-1)$ to compute jacobi symbol right?

Comment: Well, I could not put it better than poncho :) Since nothing speaks better than a picture, I'm adding one to my answer.

Comment: @satya, the Wikipedia page which you link to does contain the answer to your question - see section "Computing the Jacobi Symbol" of [the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol). It contains an explicit method that does not involve knowing the factorization.

Comment: I think Jacboi symbol is 1 if x is QR mod p XNOR x is a QR mod q :)

Comment: Nope, it's XOR :)

Comment: If one of $\Big(\frac{x}{p}\Big)$ and $\Big(\frac{x}{q}\Big)$ is 1 and the other is -1, then $\Big(\frac{x}{pq}\Big)$ would be -1 right?

Comment: yes, which is consistent with the XOR

Comment: An efficient algorithm to compute the Jacobi symbol: http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/NumberTh27JacobiSymbolAlgorithm.aspx

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau: satya is correct, it is XNOR; that's what I get for typing before thinking...

Comment: Oh right, I confused XOR with "equality test", which is XNOR - my bad.

Comment: Cool! Finally I understood Jacobi symbol. How does the attack against DDH in $Z_N$ work then?

Comment: You get $(g, g^a, g^b, g^c)$. If $c = ab$, it will always hold that the Jacobi symbol of $g^c$ will be the product of the Jacobi symbol of $g^a$ and of $g^b$. If $c$ is random, however, this will only be true with probability 1/2. I guess you can figure out the attack from there.